# Using a time stamp value (of Double data type) as a primary key in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to set an Epoch timestamp as a primary key in one of my tables in which the underlying data persistent mechanism is working using Realm. Unfortunately, the double value cannot be used as a primary key in Realm. So I am planning to use Int value instead to keep the time stamp.

Am I using the correct data type in this case? from my understanding, Int in Swift has the same size of Int32 in 32-bit devices and Int64 in 64-bit devices. Is there any possibility of issues by using Int in 32-bit devices?

Comment: Well if your epoch timestamp can have a value bigger than the max possible value in Int32, you'll get a crash. Why don't you simply store the timestamp as a `String` for the primary key?

Comment: Thanks, David. I'm looking if it is possible to keep data type as an Integer. Since it is not possible I will keep it as String type.

Comment: In Objective C Realm, NSInteger can be used to keep the timestamp. Unfortunately, there is no similar Integer data type here in Swift.

Comment: `Int64` is equivalent to `NSInteger`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor AFAIK `NSInteger` was typedef'ed to either be a 32 or 64 bit integer, depending on the machine word size.

Comment: Does realm support a proper "Date" datatype? Using that directly would be ideal. But yeah, you really don't want to use floating point numbers as primary keys, dictionary keys, etc. It's very easy to construct values that are almost exactly identical to a key you're looking for, but off by a *tiny* bit (due to imprecision accumulated during arithmetic) leading to false reports that the key doesn't exist (it might exit, but you could just be off by e.g. `0.000000000001`)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica yeah, you're actually right, `NSInteger` is typedefed to either `int` or `long`. For some reason I remembered it to be typedefed to `long` always, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica as for the `Date` question, `Realm` does support storing properties as `Date` objects, but it doesn't support the usage of a `Date` property as a primary key. Primary keys can only be of type `Int` or `String`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need a time-related value to serve as the primary key?

Comment: @Rob , I am trying to save events based on time.

Comment: If you're saving events based on time then you definitely want to store that as a Date property, not the key. Use `NSUUID().uuidString` for the primary key - it'll save you a lot of grief. Saving the Date as a property enables you to order it ascending, descending, search for date ranges, run filters against it etc. It will give you more flexibility